# Algorithm to find the "optimal" path in a given graph

Tags: graph-theory, optimization, algorithms, matlab, mathematica

Assume that $G=(V,E)$ is an undirected connected graph and that $H: V \to \mathbb R$ is a function that assign at each vertex $v \in V$ its *height* $H(v)$. Think of the pair $(G,H)$ as an energy landscape where local minima of $H$ are "valleys" and local maxima are "mountain peaks".

We indicate a *path* in $G$ from $v$ to $w$ as $\omega: v \to w$ and we denote by $\Phi_{\omega} := \max _{z \in \omega} H(z)$ the maximum height that the path $\omega$ reaches. Given $v,w \in V$, define the *energy barrier* between $v$ and $w$ by $$\Phi(v,w):= \min_{\omega: v\to w} \Phi_{\omega},$$
where the minimum is taken over all possible paths from $v$ to $w$.

Is there in literature any fast algorithm to find $\Phi(v,w)$? What is the best way to design such algorithm if we need to compute all the energy barriers $\{\Phi(v,w)\}_{v\in V}$ for a fixed target vertex $w$. Is there a clever way to map this problem into one that is well-known, such as shortest path problem on an opportunely modified weighted graph $G'$? Are you aware of any implementation of such optimization problem in software such as Mathematica or Matlab?

Any reference, idea or fruitful comment is welcomed!

Comment: You can assign the maximum weight of connected nodes to an edge to obtain a weighted graph with a modified shortest path problem where the length is the maximum edge weight instead of the sum of all weights. (Not sure if this will yield anything good though)

Answer (score 2):

The max-min version of your min-max problem is known as the *maximum capacity (or bottleneck) path problem*.  A modification of Dijkstra's algorithm works for both, and you can negate the edge weights to transform from max-min to min-max or vice versa.  See Appendix A.2 in my Ph.D. dissertation **Maximum Capacity Paths with Recourse**.  You can also transform to a shortest path problem by replacing the edge weights $c_{ij}$ with $2^{-f_{ij}}$, where $f_{ij}$ is the number of arcs with capacity at most $c_{ij}$, as described in Appendix B.

Answer (score 1):

I think of the following algorithm:

Let $H:=G$.

WHILE you can, choose a path $P$ from $v$ to $w$ in $H$.
   Delete all vertices $x$, s.t. $H(x)\geq\Phi_P$ from $H$.

This should be an $\mathcal{O}(nm)$ algorithm that solves the problem to perfection, which is probably all that you can ask for (maybe you can make it linear time).

Comment: Indeed there is a linear algorithm by [Punnen](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/0377221791900735).